# Powershell to copy files, passing source path, search string and destination path as parameters

Tags: powershell, automation

```
param([string]$username,[string]$path,[string]$searchstr,[string]$destination) 
$password = Get-Content "C:\Users\V70070\Desktop\mysecurestring.txt" 
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString $password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)} 
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.82.21.154 -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $searchstr} | Copy-Item -Destination $destination} -credential $cred
```

The above commands are saved in "C:\Users\V70070\Desktop\script5.ps1" and I execute the powershell script as

```
& "C:\Users\V70070\Desktop\script5.ps1" "V70070" "D:\Sett-Trans-New\InputFiles\Transmission\KDV\OasisNITS\Negative_Backup" "*Data*" "D:\Sett-Trans-New\InputFiles\Transmission\KDV\OasisNITS"
```

I am not seeing any execution error and the files are not copied too.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$path` doesn't magically exist on the remote computer, change it to `$using:path` inside the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock

Comment: Even after changing I am not seeing any execution error and the files are not copied

Comment: $using:var needs to be done for $searchstr and $destination as well

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PS v 2.0 ?

`$Using:` will work only from 3.0.

You can use `Param()` in `Invoke-Command`

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.82.21.154 -ScriptBlock {
    Param($Path)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $searchstr} | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
} -credential $cred -Argumentlist $Path
```